# Kann ich »i.e.« auch im Deutschen verwenden?

Tags: word-usage, english-to-german, phrase, abbreviation

Im Englischen wird alle naslang **i.e.** verwandt, und zwar quer durch sätmliche Sprachschichten. Es liest sich mit *that is* auch wunderbar flüssig und kann ständig eingesetzt werden.

Im Deutschen habe ich oft den Impuls es zu verwenden, stoppe dann aber meistens und verwende „d. h.“, „also“ oder ähnliches.

[Bei Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_lateinischer_Phrasen/I#Id) wird zwar auf die Verwendung im Englischen hingewiesen, ansonsten präsentiert es sich dort aber als lateinische Phrase, dener es im Deutschen wahrlich nicht mangelt.

[Im Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/i.e.#) hingegen bezieht sich die Schreibweise ohne Leerzeichen (englischer Standard) explizit auf Englisch. Allerdings gibt es [einen Eintrag](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/i._e.#) *mit* Leerzeichen für Deutsch.

Nun befürchte ich, dass die Verwendung (trotz lateinischer Bedeutung) wie ein Amerikanismus wirken könnte. **Wird »i. e.« im Deutschen überhaupt verwendet? Ist es z. B. in wissenschaftlichen Texte gängig? Sollte man (aus statuierten Gründen) lieber darauf verzichten?**

Comment: Wieso willst Du denn unbedingt "i. e." in einem deutschen Text
verwenden, obwohl Du weißt, daß man dafür im Deutschen "d. h." benutzt?

Comment: @Uwe: Es war *weder* die Rede von „unbedingt“, *noch* von der scheinbaren! Tatsache, man benütze dafür „d. h.“; „das heißt“ ist nur eine der Möglichkeiten, die man hat. Genauso kann man sagen „also“, „damit ist gemeint“ und vieles mehr. Das ist auch gut so. Die Frage war, ob „i. e.“ stylistisch i. O. sei.

Comment: Gut, ich formuliere die Frage anders (ohne "unbedingt"):
Du kennst die gebräuchlichen Möglichkeiten, das englische "i. e."
ins Deutsche zu übersetzen, wie etwa "d. h." und "also",
und Du hast in deutschen Texten noch nie "i. e." gesehen.
Was bringt Dich dann zu der Frage, ob "i. e." nicht möglicherweise auch
verstanden wird? Warum möchtest Du gern "i. e." verwenden?

Comment: Zum Vergleich: Seit ich gelernt habe, daß "Kartoffel" auf Englisch
"potato" heißt, benutze ich im Englischen das Wort "potato".
Ich habe mich in all der Zeit noch nie gefragt, ob ich nicht auch
verstanden werde, wenn ich statt "potato" "cartoffel" sage.

Comment: @Uwe: Verstehe den Vergleich mit “potato” nicht; *cartoffel* ist in keiner der relevanten Sprachen ein Wort. Und ich schrieb ja schon: *i.e.* ist im Englischen superpraktisch und im Deutschen offenbar nicht unbekannt. Wenn angeblich jeder Englisch versteht, dürfte ja nicht allzuviel gegen den scheinbaren Rückimport sprechen, der in Wahrheit ein lateinischer ist.

Comment: Die Juristensprache kennt für solche Gedankengänge das
superpraktische Wort "abwegig".

Answer (score 23):

Meine antiquarische DDR-Duden-Ausgabe von 1984 listet "i.e." als gängige Abkürzung von "id est"  und damit "das heißt" im Abkürzungsverzeichnis.

Bis etwa Anfang des 20. Jahrhunderts, als Latein noch die "anerkannte Sprache der Wissenschaft" war, waren wissenschaftliche deutsche Texte (Jurisprudenz, Mathematik, antike Literatur und Theologie sowieso) oft in einem lateinisch-deutschen Kauderwelsch abgefasst, der den Übergang vom einen zum andern ausgesprochen leicht machte. Dort findet man viele Vorkommen von "id est".

Ngrams findet massenhaft [Fundstellen](https://books.google.com/ngrams/interactive_chart?content=id%20est&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=8&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cid%20est%3B%2Cc0%22%20width=900%20height=500%20marginwidth=0%20marginheight=0%20hspace=0%20vspace=0%20frameborder=0%20scrolling=no%3E%3C/iframe%3E) für "id est" in "deutschen" Texten. Schaut man aber ein bisschen genauer hin, stellt man fest, dass die Verfasser sehr genau auf eine Trennung zwischen lateinischen Zitaten und deutschen Sätzen geachtet haben - Eine kurze Stichprobe hat ergeben, das die dazu aufgesuchten Fundstellen **alle** in lateinischen Zitaten oder Einschüben waren.

Da wir mit "d.h" eine sehr gute deutsche Alternative zu "i.e." haben, würde ich es lieber nicht verwenden - Es könnte *heute* wirklich als Amerikanismus betrachtet werden.

Comment: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/i__e__id_est_das_ist

Comment: @CarstenS Danke - mich hat der Duden immer an sein  Englisch-Wörterbuch verwiesen...

Comment: ＋１  antiquarische DDR-Duden und die sich wandelnde „Sprache der Wissenschaft“. Wenn es dort verwandt *wurde*, ist das ja schon ein positives Indiz. Eigentlich reiht es sich auch ein mit et al., q. e. d., etc. p. p.

Comment: @dakab "et al." ist nur in wissenschaftlichen Texten gebräuchlich, "q.e.d." ebenfalls. Du darfst nicht Wissenschaftssprache mit Standardsprache verwechseln.

Comment: @what: Habe nichts von Verwechseln gesagt. Und *et al.* steht auch bei Autorenangaben oder Bezügen auf Studien, und *q.e.d.* haben die meisten sicher schonmal in ein Schulheft geschrieben.

Comment: @dakab "et al." steht bei Autorenangaben in *wissenschaftlichen* Texten, und "q.e.d." haben Schüler wenn dann im Mathe- oder Philosophieunterricht geschrieben – also beim Erlernen einer Wissenschaft. Und dass du nichts von verwechseln gesagt hast, ist klar. Sonst hättest du ja gemerkt, dass du da was verwechselst.

Comment: Meine (jetz. und ehem.) Kollegen an den Universitäten Heidelbergs und Wiens lassen im Gegensatz zu mir  "i.e." In so gut wie jedem "rein Deutschen" Text vorkommen. Bsp.: "Aus dem Reich der Mitte wurde somit ein Land unter vielen, ein Land, das sich nicht mehr vermittelt über seine kulturelle Überlegenheit im Verhältnis zu seinen Nachbarn definieren konnte, sondern das sich mit seiner ökonomischen, militärischen und politischen Potenz auf die Bühne der internationalen Politik begab und dort fortgesetzt um Anerkennung, i.e. um die angemessene Definition seiner Position im Weltmaßstab, rang".

Answer (score 4):

Können tut man vieles. Die Frage ist nur, ob es verstanden wird, und das hängt davon ab, wer deine Texte lesen wird.

Wenn du dich an Menschen richtest, die alle Englisch können, wird man das vermutlich verstehen, ebenso, wie man verstehen wird, wenn du mitten in einen deutschen Satz »yellow« statt gelb schreibst.

> Ich habe einen *yellow* Kanarienvogel, *i. e.* einen kleinen Vogel von *yellow* Farbe.

Jemand, der nicht Englisch spricht, wird sowohl mit »yellow« als auch mit »i. e.« ein Problem haben, weil das Begriffe sind, die in einem deutschsprachigen Kontext völlig unüblich, und daher für Menschen die Deutsch, aber nicht Englisch sprechen, schlicht und ergreifend gänzlich unbekannt sind.

Die grundsätzliche Frage ist ja, warum man so etwas überhaupt machen soll. Du weißt ja, dass dafür in Deutschen die Abkürzung »d. h.« (das heißt) gibt, die genau dasselbe bedeutet wie das lateinische »id est«. Daher würde ich es für klug halten in einem deutschen Text auch tatsächlich »d. h.« zu schreiben. (So wie jeder vernünftige Mensch auch »gelb« statt »yellow« schreiben würde):

> Ich habe einen *gelben* Kanarienvogel, *d. h.* einen kleinen Vogel von *gelber* Farbe.

Comment: Dein Kanarienvogel sollte *flavus* sein, nicht *yellow*, um das Bild zu wahren.

Comment: Ich kann den Vergleich nicht ganz nachvollziehen: „i. e.“ steht für eine lateinische Phrase, die offenbar im Deutschen nicht ganz unbekannt ist. “Yellow” hingegen ist ein englisches Farbwort, dass es im Deutsch grundsätzlich nicht gibt. Ob man verstanden wird ist eine andere Frage, aber man hat sich weniger vorzuwerfen, wenn das Verwandte in einem deutschen Wörterbuch steht (so wie „i. e.“ schon und “yellow” nicht). Und letzlich ist »d. h.« ja nur *eine* Möglichkeit.

Comment: @dakab, du missverstehst da etwas. "i.e." ist Lateinisch. "yellow" ist Englisch. Viele Deutschen können Latein und/oder Englisch, deshalb sind "yellow" und "i.e." vielen Deutschen bekannt und verständlich. Dadurch wird aber weder das eine noch das andere zu einem deutschen Wort bzw. einer deutschen Abkürzung. Im Übrigen verstehen auch Amerikaner im Allgemeinen "i.e." nicht als Abkürzung von "id est", sondern als Abkürzung für "that is". Geh mal rum und frag hundert Amerikaner, was "id est" bedeutet. Die wenigsten werden es wissen. Und dann frag sie, was "i.e." bedeutet. Das werden alle wissen.

Comment: Das Englische hat die Eigenheit, dass alle derartige Abkürzungen aus dem Lateinischen stammen: "i.e.", "et al.", "e.g." usw. Es **gibt keine englischen Abkürzungen mit derselben Bedeutung**. Es ist im Englischen falsch, "that is" mit "t.i." abzukürzen. D.h. die scheinbar "Lateinischen" Abkürzungen sind im Englischen nicht mehr Lateinisch sondern dem Lateinischen entlehnt. Im Deutschen ist das anders. Es gibt im Dt. außerhalb der Fachsprachen keine dem Lateinischen entlehnten Abkürzungen für deutsche Begriffe.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Ich hatte genau das geschrieben: die Leseweise “that is” im OP, und dass das eine Lateinisch ist und das andere Englisch im Kommentar zu deiner Antwort. Und es ging auch nicht um *id est*, sondern um die verselbstständigte Form *i.e.* und deren Gebrauch.

Comment: @what - Die sehr gebräuchliche Abkürzung a.d. (AD) für "Anno Domini" dürfte durchaus deiner letzten Behauptung widersprechen. Abe prinzipiell hast du recht.

Comment: @tofro: Dasselbe gilt für *etc.* (et cetera = und so weiter)